# Solving a differential equation using Integrating Factor method

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, mathematical-modeling, integrating-factor

I need to to model a raindrop's velocity as it is falling with respect to time.

The assumptions made are that air resistance is negligible and that the raindrop is spherical

I was able to to calculate and solve the differential equation for the change in radius over time to be:
$$
r(t) = \frac{k}{p}t + r(0)
$$
where $k$ is a proportionality constant, $p$ is the density of the raindrop and $r(0)$ is the initial radius.

Where I am stuck is where the differential equation for velocity of the raindrop is given but I need to solve the equation with the integrating factor method. Given that $r(0) = 3$
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{3r'}{r}v = g
$$
where $r = r(t)$ as above and $g$ = gravitational force constant.

The solution for this DE should be:
$$
v(t) = \frac{pg}{4k} r + \frac{C}{r^3}
$$
where $C$ is the integrating constant.

I am unsure of how I would calculate the integrating factor when there is a $r$ and $r'$ in the integral as well as how I should use this integrating factor to solve the differential equation.

I was given a hint that the chain rule would help with saving some work

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious integrating factor is (choosing convenient integration constants on-the-fly)
$$
\exp\left(3\int\frac{r'}rdt\right)\overset{\text{chain rule}}=\exp\left(3\int\frac{dr}r\right)=\exp(3\ln r)=r^3,
$$
so that then
$$
(r^3v)'=r^2(rv'+3r'v)=gr^3
$$
Now it remains to find the integral of $r(t)^3=(r_0+r_1t)^3$ which is easy to do in this case.
$$
r^3v=\frac{gr^4}{4r_1}+C
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This clears a lot of things up for me.